# OpenCL vs OpenMP, How much performance difference when dealing with LBM problems?

Tags: opencl, gpu, openmp

I would like to find a suitable GPU acceleration package for Lattice Boltzmann Method (LBM) or normal Navier-Stokes CFD.

CUDA is device dependent, which is already out of my vision.

OpenCL is around 3 times faster than OpenMP when doing CFD, according to https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05316

But there is no comparison on LBM.

OpenCL is 2 times harder to code.

I am considering about OpenCL and OpenMP now, please tell me how much performance difference between these two will it be on LBM problems?

Comment: Thanks for the paper. This question is interesting to me but it's probably too broad. OpenMP offloading is much less mature than with OpenCL. That's a broad statement. Still, I hope your question is not closed quickly. It's good to see more and more questions about OpenMP offloading lately.

Comment: I read the paper. I think you made the wrong conclusion. The paper compares OpenMP on Knights Corner to OpenCL and CUDA on a Nvidia GPU. That's comparing apples to oranges. So the fact that OpenMP is slower on different hardware is not very meaningful. Knights Corner sucked BTW. Knights Landing was a big improvement but sadly Intel appears to be abandoning Xeon Phi.

Comment: even OpenMP vs OpenCL is apples to oranges. -- OpenMP deals with multithreading (CPU-only) of near arbitrary code. its fundamental idea is "this loop you wrote now runs in parallel" -- OpenCL is meant to target GPUs, with a GPU-like programming model. you don't write loops. you write a kernel, and OpenCL applies it to the data.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented LBM in OpenCL, see my [masters thesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349552856_High_Performance_Free_Surface_LBM_on_GPUs). From testing my code on various GPUs and CPUs, and by comparing performance with other multi-CPU implementations, I can say that LBM on 1 GPU is about as fast as on ~2000-7000 CPU cores. The performance benefit really is massive as LBM efficiency on CPUs is extremely poor for all CPU codes (~10-50%). On the GPU, LBM is solely bottlenecked by memory bandwidth, which is orders of magnitude larger than on CPUs.

Also, on the Nvidia A100/V100 I get 97%/100% hardware efficiency (8800/5250 MLUPs/s for D3Q19 and FP32), so you can't say you would have a performance disadvantage compared to CUDA.
I have verified that my code runs on Nvidia/AMD/Intel GPUs and Intel CPUs; it even runs on the Mali-G72 GPU of my smartphone.

So yes, I definitely recommend going with OpenCL for LBM.

---

Update: My LBM source code is now available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/FluidX3D).